# pdfbox encrypted file opens despite the password being wrong

Tags: pdfbox, password-encryption

When downloading the pdf file, I specified the password "123456789987654abc211234567899klm7654321". When opening, I can remove a few characters, for example,

"123456789987654abc211234567899kl" - file will open anyway! But if I use

"123456789987654abc211234567899k" - file not open

---

help me understand what is the problem

```
    private static void encryptPdf(
        InputStream inputStream,
        OutputStream outputStream,
        String ownerPassword,
        String userPassword) throws Exception
{
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(inputStream);
    if (document.isEncrypted())
    {
        return;
    }
    AccessPermission accessPermission = new AccessPermission();
    StandardProtectionPolicy spp =
            new StandardProtectionPolicy(ownerPassword, userPassword, accessPermission);
    spp.setEncryptionKeyLength(40);
    document.protect(spp);

    document.save(outputStream);
    document.close();
}
```

[image]

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=pdf+password+length+limit

Comment: Can you create and link to such a file? I could debug into the PDFBox source code to see what's going on.

Comment: As Ry referred to, pdf encryption only uses the first 32 bytes of a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step in calculating the encryption key from the password for pdf encryption up to revision 4 is

> The password string is  generated from  host system  codepage  characters (or system  scripts)  by first converting the  string  to  **PDFDocEncoding**. If  the  input  is  Unicode,  first  convert  to  a  codepage  encoding, and  then to **PDFDocEncoding** for backward  compatibility.  Pad  or truncate the resulting password  string to  exactly  32  bytes.  If  the  password  string  is  more  than  32  bytes  long,  use  only  its  first 32  bytes;  if  it  is less  than  32  bytes  long,  pad  it  by  appending  the required  number  of  additional  bytes  from  the beginning of  the  following  padding  string:
>
> ```
> <28 BF 4E 5E 4E 75 8A 41 64 00 4E 56 FF FA 01 08
> 2E 2E 00 B6 D0 68 3E 80 2F 0C A9 FE 64 53 69 7A>
> ```
>
> That is,  if  the  password  string  is  n  bytes  long,  append  the  first 32  -  n  bytes  of  the  padding  string  to the end  of  the  password  string.  If  the  password  string  is  empty  (zero-length),  meaning  there is  no user  password,  substitute  the  entire  padding  string  in  its  place.

*(ISO 32000-2 section 7.6.4.3.2 "Algorithm  2:  Computing  a  file  encryption  key  in  order  to  encrypt  a document (revision  4  and earlier)")*

For more modern encryption types you have a restriction, too, but generally less harsh:

> The UTF-8 password string shall be  generated  from  Unicode  input by  processing the input  string with the  SASLprep  (*Internet  RFC  4013*)  profile  of  stringprep (*Internet  RFC  3454*)  using  the  Normalize and  BiDi options,  and  then  converting to a  UTF-8  representation.
>
> Truncate the UTF-8 representation  to 127  bytes  if  it  is  longer  than  127  bytes.

*(ISO 32000-2 section 7.6.4.3.3 "Algorithm  2.A:  Retrieving  the  file  encryption  key  from  an  encrypted document in  order  to  decrypt  it  (revision  6  and later)")*